# Paging MySQL results with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

How would you split MySQL results into 'next' and 'previous' if the output was very long?

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE ... AND ...")  
  or die(mysql_error());

while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data ))
{
  echo $info['value'];
}
```

Where values would be listed from 1 to 10 and then go to next? The first page could be done with `LIMIT 10` but how would I do the following ones?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ... AND ... LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10
```

I prefer having the OFFSET word just because it's a bit more readable.

Also remember that the offset is 0 based (the offset of the first row returned is 0, not 1).  So LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10 will return rows 10 to 19.

Comment: Does MySQL support OFFSET? Much nicer than the LIMIT x,y syntax IMO.

Comment: Am I better off going for OFFSET then?

Comment: It does (as of version 5 anyway).  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html  There's no functional difference Alfie, just makes the code a bit more readable to someone else, though if you have variable names in there as ThiefMaster wrote, that also tells which is which.

Comment: It would be easier, using jquery load() function, could call the off set through php $_GET['offset'];

Comment: Just tried it, queried rows on main page for every 10 echoed '1', '2',... onclick event $('#DIV').load(file.php?id='+ id +'&offset='+ offset); Thanks for that, thanks too ThiefMaster!

Answer (score 4):

You can specify an offset in the LIMIT clause:

```
LIMIT 0, 10
LIMIT 10, 10
LIMIT 20, 10
...
```

So when building the LIMIT clause your code should look like that:

```
$offset = ($current_page - 1) * $items_per_page;
$sql = "[...] LIMIT $offset, $items_per_page";
```

Of course you'll have to ensure that `$current_page` is `>= 1`. But that's easily done:

```
$current_page = empty($_GET['current_page']) ? 1 : max(1, (int)$_GET['current_page']);
```